# Как правильно в Sublime составить комплексное регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text

Есть такая разметка с разорванными тегами:

```
<ul>
< li>цвет: синий< / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ< / li>
< li>Размер: 80 * 40см< / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
</ul>
```

На выходе должно получиться так:

```
<ul>
<li>Цвет: синий</li>
<li>Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см</li>
<li>Вес: 123 г</li>
</ul>
<h3 class="section-title font-opensans">Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue - купить< / h3>
< p class="section-content">Купить Фон для предметной съемки Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue в специализированном магазине фото/видео гаджетов. Официальная гарантия от <a href="http://www.puluz.com/">производителя</a>. Бесплатная доставка. Просмотреть все фото/видео гаджеты: <a href="https://site.com">site.com< / a>< / p>
```

Нужно убрать все пробелы в открывающем теге, убрать их в закрывающем, убрать слева и справа от тегов. А также заменить строчную первую букву после `>` на прописную.

Comment: Почему пробел слева от "Материал" пропал? Так и должно быть?

Comment: Вот именно так нужно, чтобы срабатывала регулярка

Comment: Как "так"? Убрать все пробелы между `<` и `>` в `<li>` и `</li>`, а также слева и справа от тегов?

Comment: Да, убрать все пробелы в открывающем теге, убрать их в закрывающем, убрать слева и справа от тегов. А также заменить строчную первую букву после > на прописную.

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найденное этим:

```
\h*<\h*li\h*>\h*(\p{L})(.*)\h*<\h*\/\h*li\h*>\h*
```

заменить вот этим:

```
<li>\U$1\E$2</li>
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/IHPAEf/2

```
<ul>
< li>цвет: синий< / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ< / li>
< li>Размер: 80 * 40см< / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
</ul>
```

станет

```
<ul>
<li>Цвет: синий</li>
<li>Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см</li>
<li>Вес: 123 г</li>
</ul>
```

Для любого буквенного тэга найденное этим:

```
\h*<\h*(\w+)\h*>\h*(\p{L})(.*)\h*<\h*\/\h*\1\h*>\h*
```

заменить вот этим:

```
<$1>\U$2\E$3</$1>
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/IHPAEf/3/

```
<ul>
< li>цвет: синий< / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ< / li>
< li>Размер: 80 * 40см< / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
< tag> привет мир< /tag>
</ul>
```

станет

```
<ul>
<li>Цвет: синий</li>
<li>Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см</li>
<li>Вес: 123 г</li>
<tag>Привет мир</tag>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ох, чётко. А есть вариант для любого html-тега?

Comment: @BlackFire обновил

Comment: @dIm0n если вложенная разметка

Comment: @dIm0n `< li>вес: 123 г< li>вес: 123 г< / li>< / li>` %)

Comment: @nörbörnën самое внешнее берётся. Если у ТСа может быть такая вложенность, то изменю

Comment: @dIm0n не нужно менять, мне просто нравится твой энтузиазм :)

Comment: А если в теге есть атрибуты, то не срабатывает на таких. Дополнил в вопросе код.

Comment: Есть ли решение в таком случае?

Comment: С каждым новым требованием от автора вопроса вспоминается [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2110496)

Comment: ну так получилось, я же испытывал всё в редакторе, возникают вопросы.