# Составление регулярного выражения в Sublime

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3

Повторяю условие из [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185320/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2-sublime-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) вопроса. Варианты в ответе работают, но есть дополнительные вопросы (под условием).

Есть такая разметка с разорванными тегами:

```
<ul>
< li>цвет: синий< / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ< / li>
< li>Размер: 80 * 40см< / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
</ul>
```

На выходе должно получиться так:

```
<ul>
<li>Цвет: синий</li>
<li>Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см</li>
<li>Вес: 123 г</li>
</ul>
<h3 class="section-title font-opensans">Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue - купить< / h3>
< p class="section-content">Купить Фон для предметной съемки Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue в специализированном магазине фото/видео гаджетов. Официальная гарантия от <a href="http://www.puluz.com/">производителя</a>. Бесплатная доставка. Просмотреть все фото/видео гаджеты: <a href="https://site.com">site.com< / a>< / p>
```

Нужно убрать все пробелы в открывающем теге, убрать их в закрывающем, убрать слева и справа от тегов. А также заменить строчную первую букву после `>` на прописную. Есть две проблемы:

1. В последнем абзаце предложенное решение не срабатывает на `</a>`
2. Можно ли предложенные варианты объединить в один?

Comment: Почему у вас ссылка ведёт на редактирование вопроса? Ответы предыдущие не увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

Найти

```
\h*<\h*(\/?)\h*([a-z]{1,3})\h*>\h*(\p{L})?
```

Заменить

```
<$1$2>\U$3
```

---

Отрегулировать количество символов в теге можно в этой части `...[a-z]{1,3}...`
где `{1`- минимальное количество совпадений
`,3}` - максимальное количество совпадений

---

Текст для замены:

```html
<ul>
< li>цвет: синий < / li>
< li > Материал: ПВХ < / li>
 < li>Размер: 80 * 40см< / li>
< li>вес: 123 г< / li>
 < tag> привет мир< /tag>
<h3 class="section-title font-opensans">Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue - купить</h3>
<p class="section-content">Купить Фон для предметной съемки Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue в специализированном магазине фото/видео гаджетов. Официальная гарантия от <a href="http://www.puluz.com/">производителя</a>. Бесплатная доставка. Просмотреть все фото/видео гаджеты: <a href="https://site.com">site.com< / a></p>
</ul>
```

Результат:

```html
<ul>
<li>Цвет: синий</li>
<li>Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см</li>
<li>Вес: 123 г</li>
<tag>Привет мир</tag>
<h3 class="section-title font-opensans">Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue - купить</h3>
<p class="section-content">Купить Фон для предметной съемки Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue в специализированном магазине фото/видео гаджетов. Официальная гарантия от <a href="http://www.puluz.com/">производителя</a>. Бесплатная доставка. Просмотреть все фото/видео гаджеты: <a href="https://site.com">site.com</a></p>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю ваш вопрос, то это делается довольно просто *(использовал Sublime text 3)*.

Выбираем
**Find -> Replace...**
В Find пишем: `<[ ]+/[ ]+`
В Replace пишем: `</`

После этого повторяем операцию замены с другими регулярными выражениями:

1. **Find:** `<[ ]+` **Replace:** `<`
2. **Find:** `[ ]+>[ ]*` **Replace:** `>`
3. **Find:** `>([а-я])` **Replace:** `>\U$1\E`

Возможно, можно сделать одно регулярное выражение вместо применения нескольких, однако я не вижу в этом смысла. На выходе я получил:

```
<ul>
<li>Цвет: синий</li>
<li>Материал: ПВХ</li>
<li>Размер: 80 * 40см</li>
<li>Вес: 123 г</li>
</ul>
<h3 class="section-title font-opensans">Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue - купить</h3>
<p class="section-content">Купить Фон для предметной съемки Puluz PU5201L 80x40см blue в специализированном магазине фото/видео гаджетов. Официальная гарантия от <a href="http://www.puluz.com/">производителя</a>. Бесплатная доставка. Просмотреть все фото/видео гаджеты: <a href="https://site.com">site.com</a></p>
```